# How to print train data in KFold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying out KFold after doing some beginners programs in Python. When I try to print the train data, it is giving syntax error. How to fix the error?

**Code**

```
from numpy import array
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
source = array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8])
kfoldexp = KFold(4, True, 1)
for train, test in kfoldexp.split(source)
    print(train)
```

**References:**

1. [Cross-validation (statistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics))
2. [A Gentle Introduction to k-fold Cross-Validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/)

**UPDATE**

Adding colon at the end solved it.

[image]

Comment: See into the error and you will find the location of error pointed by a `^`. Try comparing that with syntax used in tutorials.

Comment: use `for train, test in kfoldexp.split(source):`, you forgot  `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `:` after `(source)`.

Comment: @Lijo the simplest answer I can give is that it is required by Python. If you mean *why*, since you need a newline before a `while` block, I actually can't think of any ambiguity that leaving a colon off would cause.